# Error after trying to patch a file in drupal 7

Tags: windows-8, module, drupal-7, patch

I'm trying to patch this file:

https://www.drupal.org/files/935208-uploadprogress-bar-fix-129-reroll_d7.patch

Into my drupal 7 module, but each time it ends up giving the following error in cygdrive:

```
File to patch: 935208-uploadprogress-bar-fix-129-reroll_d7.patch
checking file 935208-uploadprogress-bar-fix-129-reroll_d7.patch
Hunk #1 FAILED at 463.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
can't find file to patch at input line 32
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/core/modules/file/file.module b/core/modules/file/file.module
|index b7d2f3c..9ae6411 100644
|--- a/core/modules/file/file.module
|+++ b/core/modules/file/file.module
```

The file directory is correct, and after I ran this command it ends up placing these 2 files in my folder:

```
935208-uploadprogress-bar-fix-129-reroll_d7.patch.owNkFPU
935208-uploadprogress-bar-fix-129-reroll_d7.patch.rkVjQxF
```

Why does this happen, and why does it crash?

I'm using cygdrive and I'm running windows 8 on my pc.

Does anyone have any idea's how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're applying the patch correctly? What is the command?

```
git apply [patchname]
```

Or even easier if you're using good IDE like PHPStorm there is Apply patch action there that does by far the best job applying the patches. Also make sure that you are in the right folder (to match the paths in the patch - ie. `/modules/file/file.css`)